# swa cli deployment error when deploying blazor wasm app

Tags: swa-cli

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy to static web app

Deploying project to Azure Static Web Apps...
✖ Failed to contact content server, stopping...
✖ An unknown exception has occurred

I tried to debug further and I ran
swa deploy --verbose=silly and I get the following

```
DeploymentId: ******-*******
ℹ Preparing deployment. Please wait...
ℹ Verbose logging enabled
ℹ Try to validate location at: '/Users/..../bin/wwwroot'.
ℹ Build timeout not specified, defaulting to 15 minutes
ℹ App Directory Location: '/Users/..../bin/wwwroot' was found.
ℹ Try to validate location at: '/Users/..../swa-db-connections'.
ℹ Looking for event info
ℹ Event info parsed from action options.
ℹ Could not get repository branch. Proceeding
ℹ Could not get repository url. Proceeding
✖ Failed to contact content server, stopping...
✖ An unknown exception has occurred
✖ Failed to record upload telemtry.
ℹ
ℹ For further information, please visit the Azure Static Web Apps documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/
ℹ If you believe this behavior is unexpected, please raise a GitHub issue at https://github.com/azure/static-web-apps/issues/
```